# RequireJs doesn't load dependencies correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, require

In my web-based application, I use RequireJs in order to load scripts async-ly but sometimes (not always) I get error because it seems RequireJs doesn't load dependencies correctly.

Sample:

```
require(['jquery-1.7.2.min', 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min'], function (){
    //Used for initialize bootstrap tooltip
    $('a[rel]').tooltip();  
});
```

And then I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

When creating an AMD module, you should be accepting the module output (i.e., $ for jQuery) as parameters in your custom module definition:

```
require(['jquery-1.7.2.min', 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min'], function ($) {
    //Used for initialize bootstrap tooltip
    $('a[rel]').tooltip();  
});
```

*NOTE the addition of $ as a function parameter*

Also, if you are on a page where multiple versions or copies of jQuery are being loaded (and not flagged as `noconflict` you may also run in to issues.

Answer (score 0):

`tooltip` comes under `jqueryUI` library,you need to add `jqueryUI` API added in `RequireJs` dependency.

Refer http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: No, your understood it wrongly. I **didn't** get the error always, only sometimes. That's not the answer.